# getline(ifstream, string) on Mac causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, macos, clang, c++17, ifstream

I've been a C++ developer since it arrived.  All was on windows, and I haven't touched it in about 6 years.

Now I'm trying to get an old code-base working using VS Code on my Mac.  I'm using clang++ with c++17.

This problem is vexing; I've seen many other posts with the same issue, but the problem always seemed to be something in the code.

Note: this code worked fine with C++11 on Windows.

To simplify, I copied the code to execute right at the top of main.  Here is is:

```
ifstream file("assets/textures/blocks.txt", ios::in);
if( file.is_open() ) {
    string s;
    getline(file, s);  // <-- This line causes the error.
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

As this code worked elsewhere, I assume I've got a setup or environment problem and am looking for hints towards what to check on.

Thank you for any help!

An update:

Thank you.  I paired the program down and tried a few things.  Here's the deal:

- If I leave all my files to be compiled, but replace main.cpp with the below code, the cout line generates the same exception.
- If I cull all the unused files, the code works.

Something in some other file is somehow breaking the stream code.  I'm clueless.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
using namespace std;

int main() // int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

I should add: this is a GLFW 3D game engine app.  It does not subclass or interact with any stream in any way other than the most basic file read/write operations.

Comment: Let's see the complete MRE test program, headers and everything, not just your snippet.  There's also a [C `getline` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) on Unix-like systems and I wonder if that is getting called instead.  Does anything change if you call `std::getline` instead?

Comment: I'd recommend compiling with `-fsanitize=address` for a higher likelihood of catching memory errors elsewhere that could potentially affect this seemingly unrelated piece of code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: SO must be bi-polar. MRE (meals ready to eat) MCVE (Minimum Complete Verifiable Example)

Comment: Well the code you have shown is fine. So it is something else in your app. Add files back until it breaks again. Then remove all the other files. ie find out which other file is causing it to break then show us this file. Also turn on compiler warnings and treat them like errors. `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Comment: I found it.  I had replaced a __declspec with a #pragma pack(1) prior to a struct definition.  Changing to #pragma pack(push, 1) ... #pragma pack(pop) solved it.

This was a great case of a distant error showing up in a most unexpected way!